# DC.js : Filtering dc.js linechart using dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/v7t8q3jc/10/

I made a dc.js linechart where I am showing both "impr" and "click" values .
I would like to make a dropdown menu and show only impr value on my linechart when  impr option is selected and similar case for click. But I am really puzzled with this problem as I have no prior experience with dc.

I have read other posts on stackoverflow about the same but I am unable to make something meaningful out of it. I have been stuck with this problem since a while. Please suggest me what to do.

```
{
date: 1456501820000,
impr: 1766,
click: 1235,
spend: 4860,
spendsatstart: 4860,
```

}

Above is the data sample

```js
d3.select('#val').on('change', function(){ 
    eval(d3.select(this).property('value'));
    //dc.redrawAll(); 
})
function f1() {
  ndx.remove();
    
  var dataNest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.impr ;})
    .entries(data);
    
    ndx.add(dataNest);
    dc.redrawAll();    
}
```

```html
<h2>Some Cool Heading</h2> 
  <div class="row">
    <div id="lineChart">
      <select id="val" name ="val">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="f1()">Impr</option>
        <option value="">Click</option>
      </select>   
     </div>
```

Something I have been trying to do which is doing absolutely nothing!!

[composite chart screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arePc.png)

Comment: Your fiddle isn't working well enough for me to see what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you are trying to hide stacks based on the menu. If that's it, then kindly please try the [`hideStack`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.stackMixin+hideStack) API, rather than changing the data as in your question.

Comment: Thanks for replying gordon and apologies on my behalf for not making myself clear enough. For some reason my fiddle is not working but i have added a screenshot for you to show what i am doing exactly.

Comment: Also, I have made a composite chart( updated my code) for more clarity on the problem. i want to display just one of the linecharts based on the menu selection. Thanks in advance...:)